# Value of Variable within Function NOT Changing when using If Statement in HTTP GET Request

Tags: javascript, json, get, xmlhttprequest

I have a variable called

```
let idStatus = '';
```

I need my getValues function to return true and am using this variable to determine whether it returns true or false.

```
 function getValues(){
 
 let idStatus = '';

  let getValuesUrl = 'https://something.something.com/v1.0/something/1?apiKey=1234abcdefghijklmnop';
    const getValuesRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    getValuesRequest.responseType = 'json';
    getValuesRequest.open('GET', getOptionValuesUrl);
    getValuesRequest.send();
    getValuesRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        const response = getValuesRequest.response;
        if (response) {
            if (getValuesRequest.status == 200) {
                console.log('Success');
                if(validateIds(response)){
                    console.log('ID is Valid');
                    idStatus = true;
                }
                else {
                    console.log('ID is NOT Valid');
                    idStatus = false;
                }
           }
      }
    console.log(idStatus);
    return idStatus;
}
```

```
function validateIds(obj) {
    const data = obj['data'];
    console.log(data);
    let validId = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].id == 1) {
            validId = true;
        }
        else {
            validId = false;
        }
    }
    console.log(validId);
    return validId;
}
```

Valid IDs runs the way it should and getValues console.logs the appropriate responses when it is true or false, yet idStatus always returns null.

Comment: Your code only updates the `idStatus` value **inside** the "ready" state change handler. That will run when the state changes, and that will be *after* the `getValues()` function has already returned.

Answer (score 1):

Here I've made a simpler version of your code. I used axios instead of XMLHttpRequest as it's simpler to use.

```
const axios = require("axios");

async function getValues(link) {
  const response = await axios.get(link);
  if (!response.statusCode == 200) return false;
  if (response.data.some(elm => elm.id != 1)) return false;
  return true;
}
```

```
// if the status isn't 200, return false;
if (!response.statusCode == 200) return false;
```

```
// if one id isn't 1, return false;
if (response.data.some(elm => elm.id != 1)) return false;
```

If you want more details on Array.some(), here's a link [Array.Some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)